# WKPickerItem in Objective C throwing errors

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I've got an issue with WKPickerItem in Objective C that's driving me nuts. According to the examples I've seen the following code should work...

InterfaceController.h

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController

@end
```

InterfaceController.m

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"

@interface InterfaceController ()
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfacePicker *picker;

@end

@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
    NSMutableArray *arrItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int z = 0; z <= 100; z++) {
        WKPickerItem *item = [WKPickerItem alloc]; // Line 1
        item.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",z]; // Line 2
        [arrItems addObject:item]; // Line 3
    }

    [self.picker setItems:arrItems]; // Line 4
}
```

...but I'm getting these build errors:

Line 1:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'WKPickerItem'
Use of undeclared identifier 'item'
```

Line 2

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'item'
```

Line 3

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'item'
```

Line 4

```
Receiver type 'WKInterfacePicker' for instance message is a forward declaration
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The log under the Receiver type error is this:

```
Ld /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/xxx normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/.../Developer/xxx"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/xxx.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/xxx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/xxx
    ------------
    ld: file not found: /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-aumfsqbcfcaniycmksjvgdycgvtf/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscountInterfaceController.o
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that the InterfaceContoller was included in the iOS target.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reads is if you are not importing WatchKit...

`@import WatchKit`

Comment: That's in the header file. I've updated my question with that.